# Notice: Undefined index: in $_FILES[audio_data]

Tags: javascript, php

may used upload function for the upload recorded voice. also it's work properly but the thing is its shows notice message like

Notice: Undefined index: audio_data in C:\xampp\htdocs\test-wordpress\wp-content\plugins\bookmypte\upload.php on line 4

this is my upload code for the file upload

```
var upload = document.createElement("a");
  upload.href="#";
  upload.innerHTML = "<button>Upload</button>";
  upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload=function(e) {
          if(this.readyState === 4) {
              console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
          }
      };
      var fd=new FormData();
      fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
      xhr.open("POST","upload.php",true);
      xhr.send(fd);
  })
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "))
  li.appendChild(upload)
```

this is my upload.php file code.

```
<?php
define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
print_r($_FILES);
$input = $_FILES['audio_data']['tmp_name'];
$output = SITE_ROOT."/upload/".uniqid().date("Y-m-d").".wav";
move_uploaded_file($input, $output);
require_once('bookmypte.php');
```

Comment: And `print_r($_FILES);` shows what?

Comment: it shows a blank array().

Comment: you might like to try: `print_r( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) );` in `upload.php` to see what that yields

Comment: "it's work properly"... if the $_FILES array is blank and it's not uploading your file, then that suggests it's **not** working properly, don't you think?

Comment: Anyway a) check your browser's network tool to see what's actually being sent in the request, and check all the headers etc are set correctly especially the content-type, and that the data is present in the request body. b) where is `blob` and `filename` coming from in your code? Did you check these are populated correctly when you run the append command?

Comment: Does your form have the correct enctype "multipart/form-data" set?

Comment: @droopsnoot there is no form. AJAX is being used, so a HTML form tag is not relevant here. And submitting the FormData object to XHR _should_ ensure that XHR sets the correct content-type header in the request. Hence my comment above I've asked the OP to confirm this by looking in their browser's Network tools.

Comment: Ah, OK, didn't spot that.

Comment: Like @ADyson mentioned, your `blob` variable could simply be empty, and it is not parsing empty bytes...